# How to implement a kind of dynamic scrolling div?

Tags: css, html, scroll

I'm trying to figure out a good/best implementation to create a kind of dynamic scrollable div/area.

A an example, I can create the following:

```
<div id="batchList" name="batchList"  style="height:200px;overflow: auto;" >
   .blah
   .blah
   .blah

</div>
```

The above presents a 200px vertical space... which is ok if the inner content is more than the 200px, as it the area then has the vertical scrollbar.

However, if I want to have a shorter vertical space which only has a few lines of inner content, how is this accomplished? in other works, is there a way to have a kind of dynamic vertical space, up to a max vertical space, which then starts to be scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-height):

```
#batchList { max-height:200px; overflow:auto }
```

(Also, [don't mix your CSS style with content markup](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle).)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then I think that's what you need.

Just change `height:200px` to `max-height:200px`